# Conditional Activity Start

Tags: android-activity, conditional-statements, splash-screen

I want to start the application by giving the user to disable/enable the Splash Activity at start.
I created a activity without layout and decided to load the splash activity or directly goes to main activity based on SharedPreference setting that user saves.

The concept works fine but the startup activity shows for a very short time before it switches to Splash or Main activity.
How can I resolve that?

Any other way that I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for not answering me at all!!!!

I just found that, If I make a decision on Splash Activity itself, it works fine.
In fact, On Splash Activity itself, if the SharedPreference lookup returns the True, it shows the Splash activity itself and if not, it goes to Main Activity by running the intent.
That works fine